# How to effectively use isDone() in Future object

Tags: java, future, executorservice, executor

I created a java thread pool using

`dbChangeService = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();`

I have implemented a runnable interface and added it to

`Future future = dbChangeService.submit(dbChgProcessor);`

when I do `future.isDone()` it returns `false` which is understandable because I am checking immediately after submitting.

What is the correct way of using `Future.isDone()` method so that it can produce meaningful results.

PS: I don't want to use `Future.get()` which is a blocking call.

Comment: Why don't you use CompletableFuture instead of Future?  CompletableFuture provides a broad set of methods for creating multiple Futures, chaining, and combining. It also has comprehensive exception handling support.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of simply doing `future.isDone()`, you should poll for it to be true. E.g.

```
while(!future.isDone()) 
{
 log.info("future not done yet, waiting before retrying...");
 Thread.sleep(300);
}
Object result = future.get();
```

This still is still kind of blocking, so you probably wanna do it on another thread that will notify your main tread using a lock object. Or even better why not use `CompletableFuture`? See resources [here](https://www.baeldung.com/java-completablefuture) & [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html).

Answer (score 1):

So first of all let me clarify that:

[`Future.isDone()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Future.html) tells us if the executor has finished processing the task.

If the task is complete, it will return `true` otherwise, it returns `false`.

I would suggest you to use [`CompletableFuture`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html), something like:

```
CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> {
              ...
});
```

This will return a `CompletableFuture` as well.

As I said in the comments, a `CompletableFuture` provides a broad set of methods for creating multiple Futures, chaining, and combining. It also has comprehensive exception handling support

Check a full guide with `CompletableFuture` examples [here](https://www.baeldung.com/java-completablefuture)